# How to use L.singleTile plugin in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms, tiles, plugins

I am using Leaflet (leaflet-0.7.3) to publish a WMS layergroup from GeoServer.

My code is:

```
var basemap2 = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?version=1.3.0&', {
            layers: 'Tinos_2017:Basemap_Tinos',
            format: 'image/png',
            uppercase: true,
            transparent: true,
            continuousWorld : true,
            opacity: 1.0,
          tileSize: 3000
        });
basemap2.addTo(map);
```

But the map is really slow. I tried including this plugin [L.singleTile.js](https://gist.github.com/atlefren/e6a8506046178f853101d07c19be9c93)
and change my code:

```
var basemap2 = L.singleTile('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?version=1.3.0&'', { layers: 'Tinos_2017:Basemap_Tinos',
                    format: 'image/png',
                    transparent: true,
                    opacity: 1.0,
                });
basemap2.addTo(map);
```

But the basemap doesn't appear after that.

Is something wrong with my code or the way I am using the plugin?